# How to use ExecuteStoreQuery for fetching data from Multiple tables

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, t-sql, entity

My application is in Asp.Net MVC3 coded in C#.Net. My issue is i want to get data from database using **`SQL`** query, for that i'm aware that i can use the below technique

Code to get data using **`ExecuteStoreQuery`**

```
var Complete_Data = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Mytable>("select * from Mytable").ToList();
```

**I have two issues**

1. How to get the data in `var Complete_Data` when the data is coming from Multiple table (i.e the query has multiple joins).
2. I will be generating the selecting columns dynamically. The select query columns will generating dynamically.

**Below is the sample example**

```
string Field_Formation=string.Empty;
foreach (var item in My_Parameter_Collection_Logic_Variable)
{
       Field_Formation+= item.Field_Name + ",";
}
```

Here **`My_Parameter_Collection_Logic_Variable`** is a variable declared in my code that will have a certain collection.

```
 var Complete_Data = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<What_Class_To_Be_Taken_Here>("select" + Field_Formation + "  from My_Tables_With_Multiple_Joins").ToList();
```

Need suggestion, whether it is possible to do such a stuff.

Comment: where & what error you get while doing this ?

Comment: Don't use EF for this, but a micro ORM like Dapper that allows you to materialize dynamic results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Complete_Data = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<**What_Class_To_Be_Taken_Here**>
```

<What_Class_To_Be_Taken_Here> - this class must have properties like your Field_Formation.

For example if your select is:

```
"SELECT e.idExpense AS ExpenseID, e.idVehicle as VehicleID, d.Date AS Date1  .... join ... where ..."
```

create class like this:

```
public class ItemExample
{
  private int VehicleID{ get; set; }
  private int ExpenseID{ get; set; }
  private DateTime? Date1  { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write query using join and get your data from multiple tables.

for eg:-
var Complete_Data = db.ExecuteStoreQuery("select * from Table1 as T1 inner join Table2 as T2 on T1.id=T2.Id").ToList();

You will get all column of all table and then you can access using A.ColumnName or B.ColumnName.